# Understanding WeakReference

Tags: java, memory-leaks, weak-references

I believe I have finally understood `WeakReference` and I wanna make sure I'm not mistaken.

Consider a `Map<Client,Callback> clientMap` that is a `private` attribute of a `Singleton` class called `MyService` that we use to map registered clients to their respective callbacks.

Now consider the following code:

```
// We register a client and it's callback
MyService.getInstance().register(client,callback);

// .. some code happens ..

// At this point, we decide client no longer lives anymore
client = null;
```

Up to this point, even though `client` is now pointing to `null`,  the `clientMap` stills has a reference to the address `client` was previously pointing to, causing a memory leak.

1. Am I correct?

**If question 1 is YES, Then continue:** we decide that to prevent memory leak, we should remove the object from the client map too:

```
client = null;
MyService.getInstance().unregister(client); // This methods calls Map#remove(Client)
```

Now we have fixed the memory leak.

1. Am I still correct?

**If question 2 is YES:** Due to some unexplained issues, we can't really call `Map#remove()` so this is where `WeakReference` comes in.

By using `Map<WeakReference<Client>, WeakReference<Callback>> clientMap`,  the reference counter won't increase, and once we set `client = null;` it automatically deletes it from the `clientMap`

1. Am I still still correct?

Comment: WeakReference, it's like say "Hey, i want a reference to X but i don't care to keep it always alive, if the other code don't need it anymore just garbage it and ignore me"

Comment: Please note that "unbounded memory usage" is not the same as "memory leak". If your map holds an unlimited number of objects, but you still have access to your map instance, then it is not a leak. It may eventually exhaust available memory, yes, but not by leaking.

Answer (score 1):

Well that's why [WeakHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html) exists.  No need to do Map<WeakReference<Blah>,<WeakReference<Blah>>.  Just use WeakHashMap, and it will clean itself up.  In WeakHashMap it's the keys that are weakly held onto which is fine but the value is a hard reference.  That is fine because the value will get dropped when the key gets reclaimed.  Read the docs for warnings why this matters.

Now true WeakReference will not prevent the garbage collector from cleaning up memory it points to.  When it happens is up to the VM.  Typically, it will clean it up very quickly, but under load it will let it hang around until it absolutely has to let memory go.  It's the last thing the garbage collector does when it's cleaning up memory (If I remember correctly).

Be careful with registering callbacks this way because the typically most callbacks are register and forget as in forget the reference therefore, only one thing holds a reference to the callback which is the weak ref.  And it gets GC'ed almost immediately without calling you back.  So if you do this make sure you hold onto the callback somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. When all references, not including weak references, an object is available for garbage collection on the next sweep. In your case it would not work as expected because the Map would still contain the entry for a WeakReference that points to nothing and is mapped to a WeakReference that points to nothing, with I believe no way to remove that element without iterating over all keys/values.

The second problem with your last example is that Callback is now also a WeakReference meaning it can be garbage collected, even if it is still in use, as long as no other references exist to it. Which doesn't sound like what you want.

```
Client client = ...;
Callback callback = ...;
Map< WeakReference< Client >, WeakReference< Callback > > map = ...;

map.put( new WeakReference< Client >( client ), 
         new WeakReference< Callback >( callback ) );
callback = null;
// Uh oh, callback can now be collected but client is still connected
```

The best solution is to explicitly remove the elements from all collections when no longer needed. This removes any reliance on the GC which you never really want to rely on, and there is no dangling entries in collections that will need to be cleaned up later.

Another solution is to use a [WeakHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html). This appears to do exactly what you want, it will handle any dangling entries when the key is reclaimed. It does come with it's own pitfalls. It doesn't guarantee when those entries will be reclaimed, and it will not work with circular references as values are still referenced through a strong reference. Meaning if Callbacks keep a reference to their Client it will never be reclaimed as the Callback is strongly reference which strongly references the Client, and so on.

To clarify why the 'when' is an issue with WeakHashMap, is that WeakHashMap can cleanup dangling entries whenever it wants. As long as it get's done without developer intervention. This means that values can still be strongly referenced long after they are no longer needed.

Comment: What about using WeakHashMap instead?

Comment: WeakHashMap sounds perfect, but I didn't understand this about them: Once the Client has became null, the WeakReference it was inserted in, now will return a null value. Does it means I have to iterate the map's entries just to delete dead WeakReferences?

Comment: "An entry in a WeakHashMap will automatically be removed when its key is no longer in ordinary use" No, it will be done by itself

Comment: The WeakHashMap will manage the dangling entries itself, which means you do not need to do anything to remove them. Again the documentation does not specify when an entry is going to be removed from the map. It just specifies that it will be removed without developer intervention. Which can mean the GC could tell the map to release the entry, the map cleans itself up on a background thread, or the map cleans up when the developer accesses the map.